# How to get document-term matching score in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I am using Lucene to retrieve documents using LMJelinekMercerSimilarity.

Lucene provides a score for a query "query" given a document "doc" in the variable "hits[i].score". It can be achieved as:

```
ScoreDoc[] hits = searcher.search(query, 20).scoreDocs;
int hitCount = hits.length;
for (int i = 0; i < hitCount; i++) {
    Document doc = searcher.doc(hits[i].doc);
    System.out.println(hits[i].score);
}
```

But how to get the score for each of the terms present in a query?

I want this to extend simple LM based retrieval approaches.

Comment: You can get more detailed scoring information from an [Explanation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Explanation.html).  However, if you want to extend the scoring algorithm, you'll likely need to handle that in your `Similarity` implementation.

Comment: Thanks @femtoRgon. I wanted to extend LMsimilairty so, I followed how it has been done in LMJelinekMercersimilarity to write my own LM based similairty.

Comment: @femtoRgon I found a return statement in score method of LMJelinekMercerSimilarity like: "return stats.getBoost() * (float) Math.log(1 + ((1 - lambda) * freq / docLen) / (lambda * ((LMStats) stats).getCollectionProbability()))".

This return statement should be theoretically similar as: "(1-lambda) * P(w|d) + lambda * P(w|Collection)".

But, I cannot understand how they are related? Can you (or anyone else) help.